# Need help reducing 1-in-3-SAT to show a problem is NP-complete

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, np

This is the original problem:[image]

---

And this is 1-in-3-SAT: [image]

---

I am using the `1-in-3-SAT` problem (Pc) to reduce from, in order to prove that the original problem (P) is NP-complete. I am stuck at finding a transformation T to prove that Pc <= P, such that every instance X of Pc is transformed into an instance T(X) of P, and runs in polynomial time, and that if the answer to X is `YES`, so is the answer to T(X), and vice-verso. Same for answer `NO`.

I've found out that if the number of clauses `C` is more than or equal to the number of variables `x`, then the answer is always `NO`.

I'm struggling in how to generate (transform) the string `a` (`b)` input) from in the P problem. So far, from the options I've tried, the best one has been that I generate the `a` string by concatenating *once* every variable `x` met in all the clauses, but I managed to crack it (prove it wrong), and I'm simply stuck atm.

Comment: Please replace the images with text and acknowledge the source. Images are inaccessible to the visually impaired and to search engines.

Comment: A possible way to start could be to create a different symbol in $\Gamma$ for each variable in the 1 in 3 instance and also to create a different string $t_i$ for each clause